List rows in array when the cell contain number in the string
I need to list out all data with number. I fiddle with filter and isnum but no result.
=FILTER(A1:B,FIND(v ISNUMBER(A1:B)))



Score
Remarks




3
strive to pass


6
6 pts good job


7
7pts excellant


2
strive to improve



Results



Score
Remarks




6
6 pts good job


7
7pts excellant





Here's one approach which you may adapt accordingly:
=filter(A:B,regexmatch(B:B,"\d"))



Thank you, can I know what "/d" does in the regexmatch function?

regex match for digits. Is there going to be such a scenario where the remarks can be a plain number as well(with no adjoining text)?! If so, then you should go with: regexmatch(to_text(B:B),"\d")
